# XMLHttpRequest not receiving a response when called inside a function

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, xmlhttprequest, async.js

I have an HTML form that calls upon submitting, the function-

```
function getLocationTemp() {
    temp= new XMLHttpRequest();
    temp.open('GET', 'url', true);
    temp.onload = function () {
        console.log(temp.response);
    }
    temp.send();
}
```

For some reason, I never receive a response to this API call. I have tried debugging the readyState, and i's always at- 1.

Although, when I execute the same block of code outside of the function as such-

```
temp= new XMLHttpRequest();
temp.open('GET', 'url', true);
temp.onload = function () {
    console.log(temp.response);
    }
temp.send();
function getLocationTemp() {
console.log('random');
}
```

It works, I get the data, and response code as- 4.

I assumed the issue was that the flow was leaving the function, and so the local onload was out of scope. So tried running a for loop from 0-100 within the function thinking it would give it enough time to get the response, and also put in a while loop that wouldn't exit until readystate became 4. 
But the state won't move past 1.

What seems to be the issue?

Comment: you should use onreadystatechange instead of unload, or use Fetch API (that will involve using Promises) ; both Fetch API and Promises are available in any modern browser (excluding all versions of Internet Explorer)

Comment: I was receiving the a long HTML snippet both ways. Could you share a codepen or JSFiddle link maybe?

Comment: Add an error handler to the call and see if you are getting an error message. What calls `getLocationTemp()`? Is it a button click? Form submission? Link click? My guess is you are NOT cancelling the action and the page is redrawing and killing off your HTTP request.

Comment: The flow wasn't entering onerror. What do you mean 'NOT cancelling the request'? Why would the page redraw since the request is only created after the onSubmit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As listed in the above replies, the action is re-rendering the page and killing off the request. This would be rather done as an *onclick* function handler or a change of the structure to call it using the **form** tag and its attributes like *action* and *method*.

An example of doing this via the onclick method would be -

```
function getLocationTemp() {
    temp= new XMLHttpRequest();
    temp.open('GET', 'url', true);
    temp.onload = function () {
        console.log(temp.response);
    }
    temp.send();
}
```

and in the html something like this -

```
<button  type="button" onclick="getLocationTemp()">Submit Form</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! onClick works perfectly!

My only question is- if the request was getting created only upon the onSubmit, how would it get killed since the page never re-rendered after the form was submitted?